# Unable to get response from webservice through SOAP request using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-services, soap

I have been trying to create a SOAP request using VBA but everytime I am getting a blank response. Please find the code below.
WSDL url : http://productavailabilityfeed.xxxx.com/Availability.svc?wsdl

```
Dim sURL As String
Dim sEnv As String

'Set and Instantiate our working objects
Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
sURL = "http://productavailabilityfeed.xxxx.com/Product.svc/soap"


' we create our SOAP envelope for submission to the Web Service
 'sEnv = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
 'sEnv = sEnv & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope"">"
 sEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:tem=""http://tempuri.org/"">"
 sEnv = sEnv & "  <soap:Header>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "  <soap:Body>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "   <tem:GetAccommodationByCode>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "    <!--Optional:-->"
 sEnv = sEnv & "    <tem:getAccommodationByCodeRequest>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "    <!--Optional:-->"
 sEnv = sEnv & "   <tem:credentials>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "  <!--Optional:-->"
 sEnv = sEnv & "  <tem:username>?</tem:username>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "<!--Optional:-->"
 sEnv = sEnv & "<tem:password>?</tem:password>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "</tem:credentials>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "<!--Optional:-->"
 sEnv = sEnv & "<tem:accommodationCode>?</tem:accommodationCode>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "<!--Optional:-->"
 sEnv = sEnv & "<tem:imageSize></tem:imageSize>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "<!--Optional:-->"
 sEnv = sEnv & "<tem:interval></tem:interval>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "</tem:getAccommodationByCodeRequest>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "</tem:GetAccommodationByCode>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Body>"
 sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Envelope>"

'we invoke the web service
'use this code snippet to invoke a web service which requires authentication
 objHttp.Open "GET", sURL, False
 objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
objHttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/xxxx/GetAccommodationByCode"

objHttp.send sEnv
MsgBox objHttp.responseText
'clean up code
Set objHttp = Nothing
Set XMLDOC = Nothing
```

Comment: This looks like a POST, not a GET: you are sending your content in the body of the request, not in the URL querystring.

Comment: Could you please elaborate with an example? I am a newbie with webservices.

Comment: `objHttp.Open "GET", sURL, False`

Comment: What changes do I need to make now? Only changing this to  objHttp.Open "Post" , sURL, False    should help?

Comment: Yes that should definitely help

Comment: Please find the error I am getting on doing so below.

'Run-time error ' -2147417848 (80010108)

Automation error
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Comment: Where's the error?

Comment: Have updated the comment

Comment: No idea  - I'm long-done with SOAP, and I'm off to bed.  There are plenty of examples of this to be found by Googling "VBA SOAP post" though: take a look at some of those.

Comment: I went through many but couldnt make a breakthrough. Using the endpoint url is the correct approach right?

Comment: I have edited the piece of code with the correct namespace and address location which lets me get rid of the error but the response is blank

Answer (score 1):

You definitely have a mistake in the line:

```
objHttp.Open "GET", sURL, False
```

which should be replaced by:

```
objHttp.Open "POST", sURL, False
```

This error won't let you go forward. After you correct this, it is possible that you have to debug the soap message. So, after you change this, you can tell us how it goes.

Comment: I have done that as well but still getting a blank response